# Splitting matplotlib bar graph into 3

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib

Plotting the severity of accident by the month which it occurred. My data has 3 values for severity (0,1,2) all which are under one graph. I want to create three separate graphs for each severity value.

```
month = df.groupby(['Month','Severity']).size().unstack()
print(month)
month.plot(kind='bar')
plt.legend(title = 'Severity')
plt.show()
```

[image: Current Code]

Comment: plt.subplots() may be of interest to you, if you want seperate graphs, but within the same figure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my solution using Matplotlib:

```py
# Import packages
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Create random data - Just convert your data to a Pandas dataframe
months = np.array(['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July',
                      'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'])
numMonths = months.shape[0]

sev0 = np.random.randint(13000, 15500, (numMonths,))
sev1 = np.random.randint(250, 350, (numMonths,))
sev2 = np.random.randint(20, 35, (numMonths,))

d = {'Month': months, 'Sev_0': sev0, 'Sev_1': sev1, 'Sev_2': sev2}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

# Create plots
for i in range(3):
    yData = "Sev_" + str(i)
    plt.figure(figsize=(12,10))
    
    plt.title(yData)
    plt.bar(df.Month, df[yData].to_numpy())
    plt.xlabel('Month')
    plt.ylabel('Number of Accidents')
```

where `df` is your data (replace my random data generation with your actual data).

Here is a sample output:
[image: Matplotlib]

**If you want to get fancy, you can use Plotly, which has hover and zoom features** 
Also, you can control which severity value is being plotted when all in one interactive graph.

```py
import plotly
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly.offline import init_notebook_mode, plot, iplot, download_plotlyjs
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)
plotly.offline.init_notebook_mode(connected=True)

dataAllSev = []
for i in range(3):
    yData = "Sev_" + str(i)
    
    dataAllSev.append(go.Bar(x=df.Month, y=df[yData].to_numpy(), name=yData))

fig = go.Figure(data=dataAllSev)
fig.update_layout(title="Number of Accidents by Severity Level", xaxis_title='Month', yaxis_title='Number of Accidents')
fig.show()
```

Here is the combined graph in Plotly:
[image: Plotly_Version]